# Maximage 2.0 - HTML5 Video random start

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, html5-video

I started using this great plugin : http://blog.aaronvanderzwan.com/2012/07/maximage-2-0/

The problem is that when reaching a slide containing a video, sometimes it does not start (in chromium at least). No errors thrown, it just seems to be a random behavior regarding to the video loading.

Any idea if there's a way to keep firing the browser detection or to try forcing the video play with some plugin options/controls?

Also, I could not find a way to add a play button to the page to play/pause the video...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, you need to get your  element, and then call the play() function :

The html for the video :

```
    <video id="vid_1" poster="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360">
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        Your browser does not support HTML5 videos.
    </video>
```

Then get the video element and fire the play :

```
    //video play button
    $('.play_button').click(function(){
          var video =  $('video#vid_1').get(0); //get the native browser source
          if (video.paused) {
                video.play(); //if paused, play
          }
          else{
                video.pause(); //if playing, pause
          }
    });
```

So basically you can call it whenever you want...